# ClassCastException: Long cannot be cast to class Integer while saving entity

Tags: postgresql, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

lately have been getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$summingInt$19(Collectors.java:681)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

while trying to update an entity using r2dbc save method like this:

```
override suspend fun save(entity: Entity): Entity = r2dbc.save(entity).awaitSingle()
```

there is no more logic, so I guess classcast exception thrown while trying to parse the updated entity, can't get why this could happen,

I use `spring boot version 2.7.9` and `org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql", version = "1.0.1.RELEASE`

My Entity class has `id` of type `Long` and in my database table `id` is `bigint`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `0.9.2.RELEASE` version of r2dbc driver.

I was facing the same issue while saving entity with 1.0+ version and spring boot 2.7.*

Comment: it actually did help, thanks a lot! what surprises me is that exactly same r2dbc method calls worked perfectly fine, until for some reason that exception came, I guess that exception is very inconsistent

Comment: seems 1.0+ driver version is somehow incompatible with spring 2.7.*, don't know the actual reason